# Group by string and replace

Tags: r, data-cleaning

Say for example In the data set mtcars, how do i group all the rows containing the string "Merc" and rename them all simply with the string "MERC" like

"Merc 240D"    ----->      "MERC

"Merc 230"     ----->      "MERC

"Merc 280"                ----->      "MERC

"Merc 280C"               ----->      "MERC

"Merc 450SE"             ----->      "MERC

"Merc 450SL"              ----->      "MERC

"Merc 450SLC"    ----->      "MERC

Many thanks

Comment: You can't in this case as `rownames` (like in `mtcars` car names) have to be unique. You will need to move it to a new variable first.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
mtcars$names <- rownames(mtcars)
mtcars$names <- gsub(".*Merc.*", "MERC", mtcars$names)

mtcars$names
```

Returns:

```
 [1] "Mazda RX4"           "Mazda RX4 Wag"       "Datsun 710"          "Hornet 4 Drive"     
 [5] "Hornet Sportabout"   "Valiant"             "Duster 360"          "MERC"               
 [9] "MERC"                "MERC"                "MERC"                "MERC"               
[13] "MERC"                "MERC"                "Cadillac Fleetwood"  "Lincoln Continental"
[17] "Chrysler Imperial"   "Fiat 128"            "Honda Civic"         "Toyota Corolla"     
[21] "Toyota Corona"       "Dodge Challenger"    "AMC Javelin"         "Camaro Z28"         
[25] "Pontiac Firebird"    "Fiat X1-9"           "Porsche 914-2"       "Lotus Europa"       
[29] "Ford Pantera L"      "Ferrari Dino"        "Maserati Bora"       "Volvo 142E"
```

Answer (score 1):

A `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
mtcars %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var = "make") %>% 
  mutate(make = gsub("^Merc.+", "MERC", make))
```

Comment: right, dplyr imports tibble but need to load the package too